# how would I get only the ip's and port from the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I Don't know how to just get the ips and ports

```
import requests

url = "https://proxylist.geonode.com/api/proxy-list?limit=500&page=1&sort_by=lastChecked&sort_type=desc"

session = requests.session()
scraper = session.get(url)
data1 = scraper.json()["data"]
data1 = str(data1)
file = open(r"C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\misc\a\hello.txt", "wb")
file.write(data1.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
url = "https://proxylist.geonode.com/api/proxy-list?limit=500&page=1&sort_by=lastChecked&sort_type=desc"
session = requests.session()
scraper = session.get(url)
data1 = scraper.json()["data"]

data1 = "\n".join([f"{e['ip']}, {e['port']}" for e in data1]) # list comprehension to extract desired values from list

with open(r"C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\misc\a\hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(data1.encode("utf8"))
```

outputs:

```
...
45.70.237.143, 4145
94.23.4.127, 8444
77.46.138.37, 33608
131.161.223.20, 5678
5.9.251.177, 1080
185.200.38.235, 10820
103.70.159.157, 5678
110.172.137.20, 4673
79.127.35.243, 5678
...
```